# Failed to deploy `ProxyTargetGroup` for RDS Aurora postgresql

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have deployed an Aurora cluster and a db instance (postgresql 11.8) and a proxy as AWS. When I try to add a proxy target group like below code, the deploy takes one hour and timed out in 2 hours. I have attached the screenshot. It works fine if I manually add the target group through AWS console. I wonder what wrong with my configuration?

```
ProxyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup
    Properties:
      DBProxyName: !Ref DBProxy
      DBClusterIdentifiers: [!Ref AuroraDBCluster]
      TargetGroupName: default
      ConnectionPoolConfigurationInfo:
          MaxConnectionsPercent: 100
          MaxIdleConnectionsPercent: 50
          ConnectionBorrowTimeout: 120
```

[image]

```
DBProxy:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
    Properties: 
      Auth:
        - {AuthScheme: SECRETS, SecretArn: !Ref DBSecret, IAMAuth: REQUIRED}
      DBProxyName: ${self:provider.stackName}-dbproxy 
      DebugLogging: true
      EngineFamily: POSTGRESQL
      IdleClientTimeout: 30
      RequireTLS: true
      RoleArn: !GetAtt DBProxyRole.Arn
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ClusterSecurityGroup
      VpcSubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetAPublic
        - !Ref SubnetAPrivate
        - !Ref SubnetBPrivate
        - !Ref SubnetCPrivate
DBProxyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: ${self:provider.stackName}-dbproxyRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - rds.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ${self:provider.stackName}-dbproxyPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                  - secretsmanager:GetResourcePolicy
                  - secretsmanager:DescribeSecret
                  - secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds
                Resource:
                  - "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${opt:region}:${self:provider.accountId}:secret:${opt:stage}/${self:service.name}/AuroraUserSecret"

              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:*
                Resource: 'arn:aws:kms:${opt:region}:${self:provider.accountId}:key/*'
ClusterSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow traffic to client host
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

When the cloudformation is showing `update in progress`, I can see that the target group is added and available. But the cloudformation keeps showing `in progress` until timed out.

Comment: And what are the other settings? Security groups for , proxy IAM role?

Comment: I have added proxy and its role in the post. I don't have security group yet.

Comment: If I don't specify a security group, it uses a default one which has all port open.

Comment: The proxy connects to your DB. The question is, are the SGs of DB and proxy configured properly to allow for that communication.

Comment: I have added security group for db cluster and proxy in the post. It opens all port number for incoming and outgoing traffic

Comment: For starters, your IAM role is missing KMS permisions. Please check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html) for the correct form of the IAM role for the proxy.

Comment: Also are you sure you are using `IAMAuth: REQUIRED`, not regular username and password?

Comment: @Marcin I enabled both IAMAuth and username/passowrd

Comment: @Marcin I have added kms:* in the role policy but the problem is still there. BTW, I am able to create the proxy target group via AWS console with the previous role without ksm policy. It may not work but at least it allows me to create the target group. But the cloudformation stucks there without a good error explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to **recreate** the issues using my own Aurora cluster. I had to fill out a lot of blanks as there are only few bits and pieces provided in the question.

Havever, I had **no problems** creating proxy with the **fixed role**. The full template that I've used is below:

```
Parameters:

  AuroraDBCluster:
    Type: String
    Default: database-22

  DBSecret:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:secret:postgres-wCBBqC   

  ClusterSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
    Default: sg-0f52f72631fa40b56

  SubnetAPublic:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  SubnetAPrivate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  SubnetBPrivate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  SubnetCPrivate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id


Resources:

  ProxyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup
    Properties:
      DBProxyName: !Ref DBProxy
      DBClusterIdentifiers: [!Ref AuroraDBCluster]
      TargetGroupName: default
      ConnectionPoolConfigurationInfo:
          MaxConnectionsPercent: 100
          MaxIdleConnectionsPercent: 50
          ConnectionBorrowTimeout: 120


  DBProxy:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
    Properties: 
      Auth:
        - {AuthScheme: SECRETS, SecretArn: !Ref DBSecret, IAMAuth: DISABLED}
      DBProxyName: ggggg-dbproxy 
      DebugLogging: true
      EngineFamily: POSTGRESQL
      IdleClientTimeout: 30
      RequireTLS: true
      RoleArn: !GetAtt DBProxyRole.Arn
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ClusterSecurityGroup
      VpcSubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetAPublic
        - !Ref SubnetAPrivate
        - !Ref SubnetBPrivate
        - !Ref SubnetCPrivate

  DBProxyRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: dbproxyRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - rds.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
          - PolicyName: AccessSecretAndKMS
            PolicyDocument: !Sub |
              {
                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                  "Statement": [
                      {
                          "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
                          "Resource": "${DBSecret}"
                      },
                      {
                          "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
                          "Resource": "*",
                          "Condition": {
                              "StringEquals": {
                                  "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com"
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
```

Comment: How long did it take to deploy the target group?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Maybe, max 10 minutes. Probably less.

Comment: @Marcin  I'm using the same code, but the target group taking a very long time around 2 hours for getting successfully from CloudFormation. Why it takes a long time?.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of CF stack being stuck in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS for 2 hours. My issue was that I didn't specify the `CidrIp` property on the associated ingress security group rule. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule-1.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-cidrip) say it's not required, but it is. The rule was never created and CF did't notify me.

Creating the ingress rule resolved the DBProxyTargetGroup issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue why the DBProxyTargetGroup was stucked.

Comment: `CidrIp` isn't required. One of `SourcePrefixListId`, `SourceSecurityGroupId`, `CidrIp`, or `CidrIpv6` is, however.

Docs:
"You must specify a source security group (SourcePrefixListId or SourceSecurityGroupId) or a CIDR range (CidrIp or CidrIpv6)."

I was running into the same issue but my problem was that I didn't provide any rules on my security group. Adding a rule with a valid SourceSecurityGroupId did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code but the same "Error" will come

I have to change the small change "EngineFamily: POSTGRESQL" to "EngineFamily: Mysql"

Comment: But the question states postgresql is used. Why the change?

Comment: it's not that the problem, must work with both engine

Answer (score 0):

Please give Secret Manager full access and use depends-on condition for RDS-DBInstance in RDS Proxy and Proxy-target-groups and Proxy-Endpoint then it will work. If you have any doubt then please run this command in the AWs Cloud shell. It will show you the target group's health status and whether it is available or not

aws rds describe-db-proxy-targets --db-proxy-name $DB_PROXY_NAME.

Note: If you need a full template then ping me on this post :)

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/set-up-shared-database-connection-amazon-rds-proxy/